# Factor negative from quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$-4x^2+20x-25=0$

Then you factor out -1

$-1(4x^2-20x+25)=0$

Then factor again into $(a-b)^2$

$-1(2x-5)^2=0$

In the second equation, can I multiply both sides by -1, why did the author  leave "-1" dangling in the final equation?

i.e.

$-1 * (4x^2-20x+25)=0 *-1$

which will result in

$(4x^2-20x+25) = 0 $

$(2x-5)^2 = 0$

Comment: $4x^2-20x+25=0\iff-(4x^2-20x+25)=0;$  $-(2x-5)^2=0\iff(2x-5)^2=0$

Comment: It depends on the context of the problem. If you need to find the roots, then $-1$ is not necessary. But if you need to graph the equation, $-1$ is necessary (as @JWTanner pointed out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplyung by $-1$ we get
$$4x^2-20x+25=0$$ so we will get $$(2x-5)^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the author didn't really need to leave the $~-1~$, since it will be the same anyway in this case. However, if the author wanted to graph, then the situation would be different as to graph this you need the $~-1~$.

Perhaps he just wanted to emphasize the fact that this was a quadratic with a negative leading coefficient.

Are there any other questions of this type in your book? The reason might be hidden there.

Comment: @MarsPlastic. Are you really *there* ?

Comment: whos marsplastic

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, multiplying/dividing by a number doesn't really affect the solution as much, but what's not allowed is to divide variable as it will make you lose some answer. In fact eliminating negative number make it easier to solve the equation